# Atomicness for a global variable shared by threads

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, c11

Okay, trivial question. Problem is, every answer I find on here has 3/4 conflicting answers.

I have a very simple problem. I have a global variable called ABORT_SIGNAL. As of now, this is declared `volatile int ABORT_SIGNAL`. I understand that this does not do what I wish... which is...

I have two threads which may write to ABORT_SIGNAL. It will start at 0, and go to 1 after a number of seconds. Every other thread will be reading this variable on a regular basis, checking to see if the value has been set to 1.

Would the following achieve this ....

```
#include <stdint.h>
atomic_int ABORT_SIGNAL;
...

// When updating the value ...
atomic_store(&ABORT_SIGNAL, someValue);

// When reading the value ...
if (atomic_load_explicit(&ABORT_SIGNAL, memory_order_relaxed))
    doSomething()
```

Others have also suggested that I would need to do something like the following. 
After each write issue `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);` and before each read issue `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);`

Comment: Since in the end the value will be 1, why do you need atomicness ? Whatever thread is writing, and even if they are writing together, you'll never have a incoherent value : Just 0, and then 1.

Comment: So so you think this is a case where volatile will get the job done by itself?

Comment: Yes, I think so, `volatile` will prevent optimizations, forcing the access to the variable each time it's used which is important for variables shared between threads (this is not atomicness).

Comment: @JoëlHecht *important for variables shared between threads*  You're misusing `volatile` if you're using it to share data between threads. Read this: [Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I followed the link you gave and read the article. Since it make me doubt of what I thought, I made a case test. The conclusion is unambiguous : if you turn on optimizations when compiling a multithread program, `volatile` is not useless at all. In my simple case test, removing `volatile` ends up in an infinite loop. But the article is not false, it's just that the two cases it treats are not all cases. And here, according the variable name `ABORT_SIGNAL`, I guess we are in a third case.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Making a variable volatile is extremely useful and probably the best way to solve some specific MT issues on some architectures.

Comment: I get that volatile is not a free-easy-atomic deal . But my situation here I think is different. I don't care about read and write order ... I just care that if a thread sets ABORT_SIGNAL to 1, then at some point in the next 1024 reads of ABORT_SIGNAL, the other threads get the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Using relaxed consistency makes not much sense if you want acquire semantics.

But, frankly, all of this looks much too complicated for not much gain.

Just use

```
_Bool _Atomic flag;
```

and then the usual ops, you don't need to use all these`atomic_...` pseudo functions. You get sequential consistency with that.

Then, you *could* investigate if this is really a bottleneck, and replace with another consistency at a specific place.